# Creating a batch file with WMIC commands that prompts for data input

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, prompt, wmic

I´m very fresh at scripting, and even though I´ve spent quite a handful amount of time researching, I´ve come up empty handed.

Quite simply, I need to automate this command so that more people can use it, but have no idea how to make it prompt for data input:

*

**wmic /node:(COMPUTERNAME) bios get serialnumber**

*

The objective here is for the batch file to ask for a computer name, and hence providing the requested data.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

for asking the user something, use `set /p` (see `set /?` for help):

```
set /p "cn=Enter Computername: "
wmic /node:%cn% bios get serialnumber
```

Comment: `Invalid Global Switch` without quotes: should be `wmic /node:"%cn%" bios get serialnumber`